# Remove slash from URL with htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-alias

I am using the following directive in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/user/(.*)?$ http://$1.example.com/user/$1
```

to redirect the URL

```
example.com/user/koko/
```

but it redirects to `http://koko/.example.com/user/koko` instead of `http://koko.example.com/user/koko`.

How can I remove the extra slash from `http://koko/.example.com/user/koko`?

I have tried a couple of answers that I found here but it did not work.

Comment: Should there be a trailing slash on the end of the redirected URL? Using the directive you've posted there would be a trailing slash, but in your "resulting URL" you've not included a trailing slash?

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if you included what you tried and what didn't work.

Limit the characters you want to pass, otherwise you just copy untrusted data from the client. You may want to do something with the data after the name in the second pattern.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/user/([-a-zA-Z0-9]*)(.*)$ http://$1.example.com/user/$1
```